# List items in columns from top to bottom instead of left to right

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have a list of countries in alphabetical order like:

```
Albania
Andorra
Armenia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Belarus
Belgium
Bosnia and Herzegovina
Bulgaria
Croatia
Cyprus
Czech Republic
Denmark
Estonia
Finland
France
Georgia
Germany
Greece
...
```

I'm displaying them in a list:

```
<ul class="mylist">
  <li>Albania</li>
  <li>Andorra</li>
  <li>Armenia</li>
  <li>Austria</li>
  <li>Azerbaijan</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The list displays 4 columns on large displays:

```
ul.mylist li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

and 2 on small displays:

```
ul.mylist li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This results in a list like (large display):

```
Albania     Andorra  Armenia  Austria
Azerbaijan  Belarus  Belgium  Bosnia and Herzegovina
Bulgaria    Croatia...
```

Okay, now to the tricky part: The count of countries which are displayed may vary due to filter-options. And I want to sort the countries the other way (top to bottom, left to right) like this:

```
Albania     Bosnia and Herzegovina Finland   [4th col]
Andorra     Bulgaria               France    ...
Armenia     Croatia                Georgia
Austria     Cyprus                 Germany
Azerbaijan  Czech Republic         ...
Belarus     Denmark
Belgium     Estonia
```

How can it be done keeping in mind that the CSS will fold the list to 2 columns on small displays?

Comment: Not so far, but I might if this brings an advantage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [CSS3 multi-column layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) for this. [Browser support is questionable](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) so please use vendor prefixes.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
/* default */
ul {
     -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
          column-count: 4;
}
/* < 800px */
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  ul {
       -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;
  }
}
/* < 400px */
@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  ul {
       -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Albania</li>
  <li>Andorra</li>
  <li>Armenia</li>
  <li>Austria</li>
  <li>Azerbaijan</li>
  <li>Belarus</li>
  <li>Belgium</li>
  <li>Bosnia and Herzegovina</li>
  <li>Bulgaria</li>
  <li>Croatia</li>
  <li>Cyprus</li>
  <li>Czech Republic</li>
  <li>Denmark</li>
  <li>Estonia</li>
  <li>Finland</li>
  <li>France</li>
  <li>Georgia</li>
  <li>Germany</li>
  <li>Greece</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear from Salman A answer (I only understood his answer once I read the third solution from this [post](https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float) ― the "Text Columns" one), the main part of the code to change the `li` order from left to right to top to bottom is:

```
ul {
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Everything else in Salman A answer is to make the adjustment for large/small screens