# Use a radio button as normal button

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to make a radio button behave like button

here is my html

```
<div class="options">
<label><span class="label">options</span>
 <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>
 </label>
<ul>
    <li>
<input type="radio" value="option1" checked="checked" name="radio_option1" id="option1" class="checkout_field"> optionA
    </li>

    <li>
<input type="radio" value="option2" name="radio_option1" id="option2" class="checkout_field"> OptionB
   </li>

   <li>
<input type="radio" value="option3" name="radio_option1" id="option3" class="checkout_field"> OptionC

  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.options ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:25px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}

.options li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
}

.options li {
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    /* WebKit */
    -moz-appearance: button;
    /* Mozilla */
    -o-appearance: button;
    /* Opera */
    -ms-appearance: button;
    /* Internet Explorer */
    appearance: button;
    /* CSS3 */
}

input[type=radio] {
    display:none
}
```

if i set the display of the input to "in-line" its works but with display property set to "none" it does-not work.

please note that i cannot change the html markup above as its being generated somewhere else.

here is the codepen link for the same
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRbQJO

Comment: If inline works, why can't you use it that way?

Comment: two reasons:
1. that way the actual radio button is seen i want that to be hidden.
2. you have to click the exact radio button to be able to select i want the whole button to be clickable

Comment: What is actually going to happen after the radio being checked?

Comment: @Pangloss the value is submitted along with a form.

Comment: Did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242980/making-radio-buttons-look-like-buttons-instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('.options li').click(function() {
  $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

**[pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmJLdM)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a bit of jQuery to handle the click of the radios surrounding `<li>`s.

```
$(':radio').parent('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', 'checked');
  alert($(':radio:checked').attr('id'));
});
```

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbLNdP)

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful

```
    input[type="radio"] {
      opacity:0;
      width:100%;
      position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: nice solution but user will have to click with real precision.