# Radio Button is Not Checked by Default

Tags: jquery

I got this code from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242980/making-radio-buttons-look-like-buttons-instead) for making radio buttons look like regular buttons. It works fine but the problem is that the first radio button should be checked, but it is not. Any suggestions, thank you.

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
.radio-btn-row{display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:center;margin-top: 20px; float:left;}
.radio-btn-wrapper{margin:0px 4px;}
.radio-btn{background-color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #666;color:#000;font-size:13px;line-height:26px; width:80px;outline:none;cursor: pointer;}
.radio-btn-selected{background-color:#555;border:1px solid #fff;color:#fff;font-size:13px;line-height:26px; width:80px;outline:none;}
</STYLE >

<div class="radio-btn-row"  style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: 0;">
    <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="UnStitched" name="Stitched" Value="Un-Stitched"  class="radio-btn" type="button" checked="checked" >Un-Stitched</button>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-btn-wrapper">
        <button id="Stitch1" name="Stitched" Value="Stitch1" class="radio-btn" type="button">Stitched</button>
    </div>    
</div>

<script>

$.each($('.radio-btn'), function (key, value) {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            $('.radio-btn-selected')
                .removeClass('radio-btn-selected')
                .addClass('radio-btn');

            $(this)
                .removeClass('radio-btn')
                .addClass('radio-btn-selected'); 
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is no input type radio in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the initialization.
After `$.each` you could add:

```
$.each($('.radio-btn'), function (key, value) {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            $('.radio-btn-selected')
                .removeClass('radio-btn-selected')
                .addClass('radio-btn');

            $(this)
                .removeClass('radio-btn')
                .addClass('radio-btn-selected'); 
            });
    });

$('.radio-btn[checked=checked]').removeClass('radio-btn').addClass('radio-btn-selected')
```

Comment: Not inside the each statement, but after it in the script. Updated answer

Comment: thank you, added https://jsfiddle.net/p9wq36aL/ but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Had not seen it bas a button and not an actual checkbox. Therefore :checked did not work. Use ` $('.radio-btn[checked=checked]').removeClass('radio-btn').addClass('radio-btn-selected');` instead.