# How do i style a radio input to look like a button?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm currently working on a assignment where I want to modify the appearance of radio inputs to look more like buttons.

Here's what it currently looks like:

[Current styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FCEG.png)

Below is the current HTML structure:

```css
  
  .form-field-buttons {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 16px;
    align-items: flex-start;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        flex-direction: row;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
    <p class="text-xl-right alert-required">Answer Required</p>
    <div class="question">
        <p>How confident are you in your answer?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field-buttons">
        <div class="form-field-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="active disabled" checked="" required="" disabled="" />
            <label>I'm guessing</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="disabled" required="" disabled="" />
            <label>I think</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="disabled" required="" disabled="" />
            <label>I'm sure</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I aim to achieve a design similar to these references:
[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyoNR.png)

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T8Dx.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making radio buttons look like buttons instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242980/making-radio-buttons-look-like-buttons-instead)