# How can I remove the element separation in a collapsed radio button list?

Tags: html, css

I would like to style a radio button selector like a string of buttons, with no separation between them.

I have been testing one of the solutions proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242980/) post, in which the radio buttons are basically made invisible (opacity:0;) and locked in place (position:fixed;) over the associated labels (which then will function as the buttons).

This seems to generally work well, except that I am not able to get the labels to come completely together. Any suggestion on how to get rid of the separation between the elements?

I have been trying hard to understand where the extra space is coming from, and my feeling is that it is more related to the *input* element than the *label* element - but I could definitely be wrong.

I have made a simple (close to minimal) code to demonstrate my problem, as given here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

  form                                  {   background-color:rgb(0,150,100);    /* Define some color for the form + labels      */
                                            width:30em;                         /* Not important - can be dropped               */}
  input[type="radio"]:checked + label   {   filter: brightness(1.6);            /* Mark the selected object with brigther color */}
  input[type="radio"]         + label   {   display:inline-block;               
                                            background-color: inherit;
                                            border:1px solid black;
                                            padding: 0 3px; 
                                            margin: 0;                          }
  input[type="radio"]                   {   position: fixed; opacity:0;         /* Main trick to hide the button                */
                                            margin:0; padding:0;                /* Seems to have no effect...                   */
                                            width:0;                            /* Not strictly needed - could be dropped       */}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>    
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="tester" value="1"         id="rb1" > <label for="rb1">Opt 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tester" value="2" checked id="rb2" > <label for="rb2">Opt 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tester" value="3"         id="rb3" > <label for="rb3">Opt 3</label>    
  </form>        
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

The display that I get looks like this (which is close to what I want, except for *the space* between the elements):
[image]

Any ideas on how to get rid of it?